# Engine object has no attribute cursor

Tags: python, mysql, database, text, import

I am running this code to import multiple file into a table in mysql, and the return is Engine object has no attribute cursor, I find many similiar topic, the answer is about pandas version, but I use pandas 0.19 so it might not be the reason. Could anyone help? Or are there any other way to import multiple text file into mysql

```
import MySQLdb
import os
import glob
import pandas
import datetime
import MySQLdb as mdb
import requests
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine =create_engine("mysql://vn_user:thientai3004@127.0.0.1/vietnam_stock?charset=utf8")


indir='E:\DataExport'
os.chdir(indir)
fileList=glob.glob('*.txt')
dfList = []
colnames= ['Ticker','Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume']
for filename in fileList:
    print(filename)
    df = pandas.read_csv(filename,header=0)
    df.to_sql('daily_price',engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: I found the error, this error exist if the table daily price already exists. I dont know why bcs this code should be ok to append to existed table, but when I delete the 'daily_price' in mysql database and run the code again, it work properly